# Alamofire "Generic Response Object Serialization" does not compile

Tags: xcode7, alamofire

I upgraded from Swift 1.2, xcode 6.4 and Alamofire 1.x to:
Swift 2.0, xcode 7, alamofire 2.0.2 via Carthage.

My old "Generic Response Object Serialization" broke, so I did a cut n paste from the readme, but it wont compile, it gives me the errors in the image below, help please!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The current state of the README is a mix (mess?) of 2.0 (install instructions) and 3.0-beta (code example)

Solution was to use the code example from the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/2.0.2) at the 2.0.2 release, so it was due to *my* bad knowledge of how github works.

Comment: The README and migration guides are perfectly up-to-date with each release. If you are using Alamofire 2.0.2 and looking at the README from `master` which is currently supporting Alamofire 3.0.0-beta.2, you are going to run into documentation mismatches. This is not because it is a "mess", but because we make every effort to keep it as up-to-date as possible for you, the community.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude. But I still think that its really confusing that the current README shows `github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 2.0` as installation, and then the code-examples are for 3.0. If the README currently is supporting 3.0, shouldnt the Cocoapods/Carthage links be 3.0?

Comment: No worries. If that is what is in the README, then PLEASE submit a pull request to help us out. There are currently thousands of lines of documentation and we miss some of the details even though we do everything possible not to.